# Python- re-assigning object variables within script multiple times- good practice?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class

Say for example, I have a function 'artistsearch' in class 'Scraper()' that takes the arguments 'website', 'artist', 'keyword' and 'rangenum', and I want to use this function multiple times in a script for different values. Is it the usual practice to simply reassign the variables like in the example below, or is there a more pythonesque way of doing this?

```
# Set values for first instantiation

website="https://www.examplewebsitenumber1.com/"
artist="Da Vinci"
keyword="painting"
rangenum=7

# instantiate to object devinci
devinci=Scraper()

# run function
devinci.artistsearch(website, artist, keyword, rangenum)

# Set values for second instantiation

website="https://www.examplewebsitenumber2.com/"
artist="Gaudi"
keyword="sculpture"
rangenum=9
# instantiate to object gaudi
gaudi=Scraper()

# run function again with different values
gaudi.artistsearch(website, artist, keyword, rangenum)

and so on.........
```

Comment: I think you need a list of dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's perfectly okay to reuse a variable (you're just reassigning the name to something else), but in your case, you seem to need a loop & a list of dictionaries to pass as keyword arguments

```
arglist = [
    {
        website: "https://www.examplewebsitenumber1.com/",
        artist: "Da Vinci",
        keyword: "painting",
        rangenum: 7
    }, {
        website:"https://www.examplewebsitenumber2.com/",
        artist: "Gaudi",
        keyword: "sculpture",
        rangenum: 9
    }
]

for args in arglist:
    devinci = Scraper()
    devinci.artistsearch(**args)
```

`**args` passed as arguments is the same as unpacking the current dictionary. Example:

```
devinci.artistsearch(
    website="https://www.examplewebsitenumber2.com/",
    artist="Gaudi",
    keyword="sculpture",
    rangenum=9
)
```

I'm of course not sure of the argument names in `artistsearch`, but you get the idea (at worst, create a list of lists instead and pass arguments as positional, `artistsearch(*args)` in that case)

Comment: Both answers so far were good but this one gave me some additional insight that I can now expand on. Can I ask about the double ** and the single *. What do they signify?

Comment: Oh crap, didn't realize that I could edit without getting it approved. I updated the formatting of `arglist` and the function call to be more pretty, revert it if you don't like it.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest list of `list`.

```
to_scrape = [["https://www.examplewebsitenumber1.com/", "Da Vinci", ..], ["https://www.examplewebsitenumber2.com/", ..]]
instance=Scraper() #if you need define this inside for loop.
for i in to_scrape:
    instance.artistsearch(*i)
```